# Are there any underlying effects of not using reactive kafka consumer in spring webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

If I use blocking consumer, would it affect the webflux threads handling HTTP calls? I know spring kafka consumes messages in a separate thread and I am using `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

Comment: I don't see a correlation between a Kafka consumer and WebFlux server: they both are input endpoint to your application. Therefore they both don't effect each other and doesn't matter how they are configured.